Find out a curent map location view in Android map
MainActivity:
package com.example.demotask;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fetchLocation();
    }

    private void fetchLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    currentLocation = location;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentLocation.getLatitude() + "" + currentLocation.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                    assert supportMapFragment != null;
                    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("I am here!");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 5));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    fetchLocation();
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

I tried lot of times but only Google screen comes, a map location never comes. What can I try next?
